# Webservice and encoding

Tags: c#, web-services, encoding

I connect to the web service as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "http://mywebserviceaddress.com/attributes=someatt");
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(
       req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),Encoding.UTF8))
{
      strResponse = stIn.ReadToEnd();
      return strResponse;
}
```

However I get the response with (probably) bad encoding so as a result, on my page i get the following issue:

[image: encoding failure]

Am I doing something wrong or is it a third-party web service issue? How can I get the respone without this silly issues?
Here's the screenshot from debugger:

[image]

Comment: What encoding is the page in? How are you getting the response and putting it on the page?

Comment: I think it's not the page-encoding-issue. When I debug the code my strResponse variable at that stage has value from web service encoded wrong.

Comment: Sounds likely in that case (you really should have added that information to the question). Are you sure the stream you are reading is UTF8?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I ensure it's UTF8?

Comment: I don't see these issues in the text visualizer image you posted. Are they there?

Comment: @Oded - I edited the post - actually with an appropriate screenshot

Comment: Did you check the headers returned by the remote web service? Are you sure this is UTF8? If the server is in your control, you might be able to do something about that.

Comment: The server is not in my control. How can I check the headers returned by the web service?

Comment: You can do it with a little modification of your code, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is probably not *UTF8*. It looks like special characters use the upper half of an ASCII character, so it's some kind of old charset. Reading it as UTF8 causes errors because the reader doesn't expect single-byte special characters.

Store the result of `GetResponse()` into a variable and output the contents of <del>`ContentType`</del>`CharacterSet`. If the server acts correctly, it shows the used charset in this property. Then, you can use the correct charset in your `StreamReader`.

Comment: I get the folowing result from the GetResponse().ContentType = "text/xml". I see that the CharacterSet from System.Net.HttpWebResponse is set to: "ISO-8859-1". It seems that here's the problem. Is it?

Comment: I see, I didn't see that property. So the character set of the response is *ISO-8859-1*. Use `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` instead of Encoding.UTF8.

Comment: it seems very strange to me. I've change the encoding as you suggested but it have the following results: "ruin jednego z najwiêkszych kompleks&amp;oacute;w pa³acowo-ogrodowych staro¿ytnoci, gdzie cesarz Hadrian spêdzi³ ostatnie lata ¿ycia."

Comment: How does the page look in a ordinary browser? In Firefox, you can view the used charset using the context menu > Page Information or something like that.

Comment: And how does it look in a browser? Does it display the special characters correctly, or does it show the wrong characters?

Comment: It shows the wrong characters. Here's the link how it looks in a browser: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/267/encodingfailure3.png/

Comment: Ok, so it's incorrect in the browser, too. Then of course it's not a bug in your application, but one of the server. Tell the server admin to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Yogu. I will inform the company responsible for that webservice and wait for their response